# Installing Zend framework on Xampp on Windows 7, cant find projectname.loc

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am trying to Install Zend framework on my computer. I did everything as said in this tutorial http://samminds.com/2012/07/zend-framework-2-installation-on-xampp-for-windows/. Everything went fine. I did not get any errors.But now I am trying to go to www.projectname.loc I get 404 error. I didnt find any help from googleing about this. What could be the problem here? What should I check, I already tried to install zend 2 times.

Comment: Is your virtual host is pointing to public directory of zf2 skeleton?

Comment: And enable error reporting in index page to true, so, you can get error message.

Comment: And Yes, did you inserted new entry with "127.0.0.1 www.projectbane.loc" in "hosts" file ??

Comment: Yes I inserted "127.0.0.1 www.projectbane.loc" in hosts file.

Comment: Error reporting is on?
can you try with localhost/projectName/public for test...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was in this code:
(This is working version)
    
        DocumentRoot "C:/xampp2/htdocs/ZendSkeletonApplication/public"
        ServerName www.projectname.loc
        ServerAlias projectname.loc
        
            DirectoryIndex index.php
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all

Before I just copied code from tutorial and it looked like that:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJECTNAME/public"
    ServerName www.projectname.loc
    ServerAlias projectname.loc
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/PROJECTNAME/public">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What is difference between these two? PROJECTNAME can be any thing.. like zf2 or myproject etc.